# http:// and http://www. to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Perhaps someone can help me. I need a rewrite rule like this: redirect from `http://` and `http://www.` to `https://www.mydomain`.

For example, someone types in `mydomain.com` he gets redirected to `https://www.mydoamin`, if he types in `www.mydomain.com` he gets redirected to `https://www.mydomain`. So if someone types in `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` he should get redirected to `https://www.mydomain`

Also if possible to redirect to a subdomain like `login.mydomain.com` -> `https://login.mydomain.com`

Everything to HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found a little typo to fix in my last comment, and want to know which part is wrong if these config not works as you expected:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Above consists of two parts:

1. If url was not starts with https://, redirect to https://www.mydomain.com/ regardless of the hostname or rest of the url
2. If url hostname is not www.mydomain.com, redirect to https://www.mydomain.com/ , in any case the url is http:// or https://

UPDATE:
Finally, got a chance to test by myself. Matching rules didn't work as I expected, for some reason. Replaced wildcard ($1) as %{REQUEST_URI}, and pattern ^/(.*)$ as .*.

Answer (score 3):

here's what you can put in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I think @BookOfZeus's solution won't rewrite to a canonical host name if the original url starts with https:. How about `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed one more condition. Maybe we need to separate ruleset for http-to-https rewrite and host name normalization. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` `RewiteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com` `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2):

Both of your codes don't work.

At the moment I have this one and that works but only for http (without "s")

```
# http to www #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\..* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^.*\..*\..* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```